# Angular2 toString can't get third attribute of Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <p><strong>Email:</strong> {{email}}</p>
  <p><strong>Address:</strong> {{address.street}}, {{address.city}}, {{address.country}}.</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Strahinja';
  email = 'strahinja@gmail.com';
  address = {
    street: 'Boulevard of king Alexander',
    city: 'Belgrade',
    country: 'Serbia'
  }
  addressToString(): string {
    return this.address.street + ', ' + this.address.city + ', ' this.address.country;
  }
}
```

I want to be printed out next: `Address: Boulevard of king Alexander, Belgrade, Serbia` 
What I receive as output is `Address: [object Object]` as it should. 
 I know that there's a way to print all the data I would like by writing next:
`Address: {{address.street}}, {{address.city}}, {{address.country}}`. 
And I know there's a way to create a `toString()` method as there's a way in Java and I tried to do it by some exploring the web, however I get a compilation error on the last `this` in last line and it says next: `';' expected. Unreachable code detected.` 
Any suggestion, guys? Is it possible that it's possible only to get 2 attributes in a Class in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
return this.address.street + ', ' + this.address.city + ', ' this.address.country;
```

to

```
return this.address.street + ', ' + this.address.city + ', ' + this.address.country;
```

You're missing a '+' between the ', ' and this.address.country

Comment: It's all good ... sometimes we just need that second pair of eyes

Answer (score 2):

Do I see a typo here? I think you are missing a **+** before `this.address.country`

```
return this.address.street + ', ' + this.address.city + ', ' this.address.country;
```